# SpriteKit objects not colliding with each other

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm working on my first SpriteKit project and I'm having problems getting collisions to work. The objects just pass right through each other.  I thought just setting the category, collision and contact bitmasks would be all that was required. I'm defining my two objects like so:

```swift
final class Paddle: SKShapeNode {
    init(isLeft: Bool) {
        super.init()

        ...

        path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)

        let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rect.size)
        body.category(.paddle, collidesWith: .ball, isDynamic: false)

        physicsBody = body
    }
}

final class Ball: SKShapeNode {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        ...

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
        path = CGPath(ellipseIn: rect, transform: nil)
     
        let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        body.category(.ball, collidesWith: .paddle)
        body.linearDamping = 0
        body.angularDamping = 0
        body.restitution = 1.0

        physicsBody = body
    }
}
```

and then I added a helper extension to setup the common physics body properties:

```swift
extension SKPhysicsBody {
    func category(_ category: ShapeType, collidesWith: ShapeType, isDynamic: Bool = true) {
        categoryBitMask = category.rawValue
        collisionBitMask = collidesWith.rawValue
        contactTestBitMask = collidesWith.rawValue
        fieldBitMask = 0
        allowsRotation = false
        affectedByGravity = false
        friction = 0
        restitution = 0
        self.isDynamic = isDynamic
    }
}
```

Comment: In GameViewController file, I would have ".showsPhysics = true" so you can see the physics bodies to make sure they look ok (put the code where you may have ignoreSiblingOrder = true). You really need to show the physics contacts collision code as it maybe something in there, I think your categories,collisions,contacts seem ok.

Comment: This is in SwiftUI, there's no view controller. I don't have actual collision code.  I thought just setting those masks was all it took :(

Comment: Right ok. Try searching "hackingwithswift collision detection", that should get you started with dealing with the physics engine and collisions.

Comment: Isn't that delegate all about taking "custom" actions when collision occurs?  I don't need to know it collided, I just want the ball to bounce off of the paddle.

Comment: You need to set the GameScene as SKPhysicsContactDelegate, and then add code in didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)

Comment: OK, this is strange. I see my ball at the lower left of the screen (0,0), and my paddle on the far right, where I'd expect it to be. The `didBegin(_:)` method is saying a collision between the two occurred, and that the paddle has position (9,27).